# 500 error on Joomla website

Tags: php, joomla, error, phpbb, http-code-500

```
PHP Fatal error: Call to a member function setQuery() on a non-object in /home/josh/public_html/administrator/components/com_jfusion/plugins/phpbb3/forum.php on line 226
```

Just moved over to a new server. Anyone have ideas as to what is wrong?

Is this a database issue?

line 226:

```
 //get permissions for all forums in case more than one module/plugin is present with different settings
        $db = & JFusionFactory::getDatabase($this->getJname());
        $query = "SELECT forum_id FROM #__forums WHERE forum_type = 1 ORDER BY left_id";
        $db->setQuery($query); //226
        $forumids = $db->loadResultArray();
```

Comment: Did you move also the database? Did you changed the data to access the database accordingly?

Answer (score 1):

Please post the code which causes this error (line 226).

To try a shot in the dark you can check the cURL settings 
See: [Plugin Config](http://wiki.jfusion.org/doku.php?id=smf%3aconfiguring) in the JFusion Documentation Wiki.

It is also possible that you can not access the database or the database settings are incorrect.

See [this screenshot about the database configuration](http://www.jfusion.org/wiki/lib/exe/detail.php?id=smf%3aconfiguring&media=install%3aconfig%3aplugin_congif_database.jpg) in the JFusion Documentation Wiki.

Comment: posted above in first post

Comment: Please check the DB settings (2nd link in my first post)

Comment: Those are set in a config file right?

Comment: Yes, the config of this component. For all possible settings have a look here: http://www.jfusion.org/wiki/doku.php?id=smf:configuring 

That should sound familiar to you.